# use proxy or redirect to file if cookie is set and only for a subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, proxypass

I am currently trying to send the request either through a proxy or to a PHP file based on a cookie. The rule only apply to `/api`.

This is what I have so far. It is part of my VirtualHost Config:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Cookie is not set. Send all request from /api/$ to local-file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bexample_cookie=true\b
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /local-php.php [L]

# Cookie is set. Send all request to the proxy.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} \bexample_cookie=true\b
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://proxy-domain.local/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /api http://proxy-domain.local
```

My requests are now routed correctly based on the cookie. But unfortunately this is global and not only if the path begins with `/api`. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Cookie is set. Send all request to the proxy.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*|)$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} \bexample_cookie=true\b
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://proxy-domain.local/$1 [P,L]
> ```

The first condition is only successful when the `REQUEST_URI` does *not* start with `/api`. However, this condition would seem to be redundant, since you can perform the same check in the `RewriteRule` directive itself, which currently matches *everything*.

For example:

```
# Cookie is set. Send all request to the proxy.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} \bexample_cookie=true\b
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://proxy-domain.local/$1 [P,L]
```

Note that this requires the request to start with at least `/api/`, not `/api` - is that OK?

However, I would also question the logic of the first rule block:

> ```
> # Cookie is not set. Send all request from /api/$ to local-file.php
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(/.*|)$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bexample_cookie=true\b
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /local-php.php [L]
> ```

Apart from not doing what the *comment* states, this rewrites the URL when the request does *not* start `/api` AND the cookie is not set. What if the cookie is set? This also won't rewrite a request for the root directory itself - which maybe intentional if the DirectoryIndex is already set correctly?